# How can I join climate data to cities with dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, dbpedia

I am trying to get a dataset that gives me all the data available in [a city's climate table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nantucket#Climate) but I'm having some trouble.

I was able to get this to work and felt pretty good about myself. When I plug this in on [dbpedia's virtuoso client](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) this gives me all the cities that dbpedia has, and all of their countries.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?city_name ?country
WHERE { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City ; 
          rdfs:label ?city_name; 
          dbpedia-owl:country ?country 
   FILTER (langMatches(lang(?city_name), "EN")) .
}
```

Update: I have found properties that seem to give what I'm looking for (e.g. dbpedia.org/property/aprHighC) but I'm having trouble adding them to my output.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?city_name ?country ?aprHighC
WHERE { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City .
    ?city rdfs:label ?city_name .
    ?city dbpedia-owl:country ?country 
FILTER (langMatches(lang(?city_name), "EN")) .
}
```

Gives an error: `Variable 'aprHighC' is used in the query result set but not assigned`. How do I assign it?

Comment: I don't think this property is used in DBpedia. Just try `SELECT *
 { ?s dbo:climate ?climate .}` you'll see that you won't get any results. Or open a resource page for any `dbo:Place` which is the domain of `dbo:climate` and try to find any property related to climate.

Comment: I don't think that those tables are processed by the DBpedia extraction framework. I now that there is some ongoing research to extract such data, but for now the data comes primarily from the infoboxes on the right hand side of a Wikipedia entry page. Or from where did you get the climate data?

Comment: I made a small update. Does anyone have input on the new problem?

Comment: `?aprHighC` needs to be bound in the `WHERE` clause (some SPARQL engines will ignore this and just return results with the variable unbound).

Comment: @scotthenninger honestly I can't figure out how to do that without getting an error...

Comment: Just remove `?aprHighC` from the SELECT statement.

Comment: You have to add a triple pattern in which `?aprHighC` occurs if you want to get that information from the knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query gives the January average daily high (°C). Adding other climate items is as simple as copying the line beginning "OPTIONAL" and changing the item and variable name from janHighC to whatever you are trying to get.

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT * {
{ ?city rdf:type dbo:City .
 ?city rdf:type schema:City .
 ?city rdfs:label ?name
}
OPTIONAL {?city dbp:janHighC ?janHighC .}
}
```

I will note, however, that most cities don't have this information. I had to give up on getting the data this way.

Answer (score 2):

For the query to get results in the second query, a city has to have a three properties: `rdfs:label`, `dbpedia-owl:country` and `dbpedia-owl:climate`.  Your query pretty much proves that DBPedia data has cities with label and country properties, but not climate.  Try the following to see just what properties are found for members of `dbpedia-owl:City`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE {
   ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City ;
      ?p ?o .
}
```

Note that not all members of `dbpedia-owl:City` will have these properties, but it gives you a range of what properties are used.

Looking at it the other way, you can ask what entities use the `dbpedia-owl:climate` property:

```
SELECT ?s
WHERE {
   ?s dbpedia-owl:climate ?climate 
}
```

I didn't find any, so it could be the case that the prefix is different than the one you are using?  I'd suggest double-checking the property name.

Regardless, it's a good idea to use SPARQL to find what is actually in the data store.  And use `LIMIT` to look at parts of the data without overwhelming the system.

Comment: The first query was really helpful! I think all the properties I'm looking for are here (e.g. aprHighC) so I'll be trying to pull them that way. Should I update my question or post an answer once I have the working query?